# Index nested collections in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I try to edit Firebase database rules and to add indexes. I want to index both the big collection (product) and one of its subcollections(bids). I tried this way.
For indexing the big collection, I need to do this:

```
"product": {
    ".indexOn":["initial_price"]
}
```

And for indexing the subcollection, I need to do:

```
"product": {
    "$productId":{  
        ".indexOn":["amount"]        
    },
}
```

How can I bring these two together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"product": {
    ".indexOn":["initial_price"],
    "$productId":{  
        ".indexOn":["amount"]        
    }
}
```